# How to load a BigQuery table to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I have a 32 GB table in BigQuery that I need to do some adjustments through Jupyter Notebook (using Pandas) and export to Cloud Storage as a .txt file.

How to do this ?

Comment: I'm guessing that this amount of data will be too large to manipulate in pandas since it's recommended to have [5-10x the amount of RAM as the size of your dataset](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/).  Can you do your manipulation with SQL directly in BigQuery and then export as @Alfons recommended in his answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can [only export 1 GB at a time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) so your best bet is probably to query the first 1 GB worth of rows then next 1 GB, etc. and save them individually that way. That can all be scripted with the `bq` tool once you know approximately how much storage each row takes up. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Platform Console to do that.

1. Go to Bigquery in the Cloud Console.
2. Select the table you want to export and select "Export" then Export to GCS.
3. As your table is bigger than 1GB, be sure to put a wildcard in the filename so Bigquery exports the data in 1GB approx chunks (i.e export-*.csv).

You cannot export nested and repeated data in CSV format. Nested and repeated data are supported for Avro, JSON, and Parquet (Preview) exports. Anyway, the form will tell you if you can when you try to select the file format.

Comment: That won't do because I still need to do some transformation though Pandas as the table needs some adjustments.

Comment: You can access the CSV files from Jupiter notebook and do the manipulations. or do you need to manipulate the data prior to export it? if so, you will need to do some SQL syntax.